# Atom folding HTML like Sublime Text?

Tags: atom-editor, code-folding

Tried to switch from Sublime to Atom like two years ago, but after days of searching couldn't find a reasonable way to make the text fold like in Sublime text (showing the closing tag as well).

Two years later, today, I really want to give it one more try and I still can't find a way to make the folding work with atom settings or any plugins.

If there is a way to give Atom the folding properties of Sublime Text, can anyone give a me link or instruction or whatever how do make it happen ?

P.s: Is it really impossible to do or I just plainly suck at searching online?

Answer (score 0):

https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/folding/

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> folds the code. Alternately you can toggle the arrow button just like you can in Sublime.

Replace <kbd>Cmd</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if you are on Windows or Linux.